# Dividing a matrix by another matrix of equal size to get a scalar value

Tags: matlab

I am working on this question in MATLAB where I need to find a matrix named B that is the dimension 64x1. Each value of this matrix is equal to a formula as such:

```
B(i,1) = log((S(:,:,1)/S0)/b)
```

Where S(x,y,z) is a 115x94x64 matrix, S0 is a 115x94 matrix, and b is a constant value. The trouble I am having at the moment though is that my equation above won't work because my expression is coming to a 115x115 matrix when it needs to be a constant value.

My question is if there is anyway when dividing one matrix of equal size by another, you can find a constant value, or if I need to completely reconsider how I am approaching this question?

Kind regards.

Comment: you probably need to reconsider how yo are approaching this question. division will never give you a scalar here.

Comment: I have figured out an approach for that now but now I have come across another difficulty. I have one 64x6 matrix and one 64x115x90 matrix, and I want to use QR decomposition to end up with a 6x115x90 matrix (or something of a similar dimension to that) but I can't quite figure out how exactly to do that. Is there any source you might be able to point me towards that would help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: You need to define your operations better, we can not help with that. What you describe is not any "standard" division so you need to explain to us what is divided with what, and then we can help with the code.

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion but I think I have solved my troubles. What I had meant was I had a formula A*D = B where I knew A (64x6 matrix) and knew B (64x115x90 matrix) and I wanted to find D by using QR Decomposition (i.e. A / B) where D would be a 6x115x90 matrix. What I ended up doing to make it easier was finding the pseudoinverse of A and multiplying it by B to find D which seems to have given me the answer I was after.